# how to use returned values from python

Tags: python

So I have a function like this one below called analysis1.py :

```
import glob
import panda as pd   
def my_function(test_path):
    path=test_path +"\\"+ "*mainlog.txt"
    files =glob.glob(path)
    for name in files:
        lines=[line.rstrip('\n')for line in open(name)]
        if "a:" in lines:
            k_1=pd.Dataframe1
            return k_1
        elif "b:" in lines:
            k_2=pd.Dataframe2
            return k_2
        elif "c:" in lines:
            k_3=pd.Dataframe3
            return k_3
        elif "d:" in lines:
            k_4=pd.Dataframe4
            return k_4
        elif "e:" in lines:
            k_5=pd.Dataframe5
            return k_5
```

I want to make a code that finds out what is returned from the function and use the returned value to calculate some stuff. Each returned value is used to calculate something different like in a different code store in the same directory as the previous and named main_code.py :

```
returned_value = analysis1.my_function(test_path)
if returned_value == k_1:
    do_something_1
if returned_value == k_2:
    do_something_2
if returned_value == k_3:
    do_something_3
if returned_value == k_4:
    do_something_4
if returned_value == k_5:
    do_something_5
```

What can I add to this code that can help me to know what is returned and use it solve the problems shown. I know am missing something small but can't quite figure out what it is.

Comment: `r = my_function(my_arg)` will call `my_function`, passing it `my_arg` and saving the return value in `r`.  You can then compare `r` to the different expected return values.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: That's a fairly large change you made to your code by adding that single line (it's also still not doing what you think it's doing... `==` vs `=`). That code change, though, invalidates all three answers you've gotten in some way. Next time you post a question, ensure that your example contains *all* of your code you are having problems with.

Comment: @Andy thanks for letting me know about that actually made a mistake with my code. it is actually returned_value = my_function(test_path) in the original code. Sorry for not including it. But that is what I have actually worked with but it seems not to be giving me what I really want.

Comment: @RickyMos Is `k_1` to `k_5` defined? Is `test_path` defined? Since you can do the `=` operation, what do you mean by "help me to know what is returned"?

Comment: @RickyMos and what do you mean by "help me to know what is returned"?

Comment: @Moon Cheesez. This is just part of the  code. test_path is defined. And 'k_1 'to 'k_5' is a Dataframe already defined. The first and second code are not in the same place. am importing the returned values in code 1 to use in code 2. When I use this:  'returned_value = my_function(test_path)'. and try to run code 2, I get an error that 'k_1' to 'k_5' is not defined

Comment: @RickyMos Please include your filenames and how you import the variables.

Comment: @Moon Cheesez. I edited the question to include the variables imported. All the variables are already defined. The problem is that am handling a lot of data where by I will have all of the dataframe from k_1 to k_5 and they have different columns so the calculation are different. I need to come up with a code that will provide information for all of the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how functions work in Python. Functions are like your pocket tools in the world of programming. You can use them anytime you want and they will `return` you something -- Like a calculator returns 2 when you type 1+1.

Similarly, all you need to do is run the function (with its required arguments) and it will `return` you something. You can simply do this:

```
returned_value = my_function(my_arg)
```

When a function returns a value, you can think of it as replacing the whole function call with that value. So, the statement will be like:

```
returned_value = "some returned value"
```

After that, you can carry on with whatever you were doing.

If each `if` statement has a different argument in the function, remember, replace the function call with the returned value and see if it makes sense:

```
if my_function(arg_1) == k_1:
    do_something_1
if my_function(arg_2) == k_2:
    do_something_2
if my_function(arg_3) == k_3:
    do_something_3
if my_function(arg_4) == k_4:
    do_something_4
if my_function(arg_5) == k_5:
    do_something_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your `if returned_value` lines, add this:

```
returned_value = my_function(test_path)
```

This will assign the value returned from `my_function` to `returned_value`. At that point, your `if` statements will begin checking the value to see if it matches an expected value. If so, the appropriate `do_something_*` function will be called.

A few notes:

- In your function, the returned values are variable names (`k_1`, `k_2`, etc.) The values need to be assigned *somewhere* before they can be called otherwise you'll get a `NameError` exception.
- Assuming that the `do_something_*` calls are to functions, you need to change the calls from `do_something_1` to `do_something_1()` (notice the parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the variables: `k_1` .. `k_5` are not defined to hold values. Define them first somewhere. It seems like you are looking for something equivalent of an `enum`.

```
from enum import Enum

KType = Enum('KType', 'k_1 k_2 k_3 k_4 k_5')
```

You can then do:

```
..  
..
if "a:" in lines:
    return KType.k_1
elif "b:" in lines:
   return KType.k_2
elif "c:" in lines:
   return KType.k_3
elif "d:" in lines:
   return KType.k_4
elif "e:" in lines:
   return KType.k_5
```

.. And then to compare, you can do:

```
returned_value = my_function(path)
if returned_value==KType.k_1:
  do_something_1
if returned_value==KType.k_2:
  do_something_2
if returned_value==KType.k_3:
  do_something_3
if returned_value==KType.k_4:
  do_something_4
if returned_value==KType.k_5:
  do_something_5
```